# How to suspend / resume the events of a particular component in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Can anyone please let me know how to suspend/resume the events of a particular component. For example

`textfieldObj.suspendEvents();`
This will suspend all the events of that particular component means which will not fire any event listener if action happens also.

`textfieldObj.resumeEvents();`
All the events of that component will be fired if action performs.

Is there any thing like this in titanium?

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi.

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium you can add and remove eventListeners. This goes for all Titanium types which are capable of firing events.

If you want to receive all events of a type (e.g. click) use

```
textfieldObj.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // perform your action
});
```

If you don't want to receive anymore events use

```
textfieldObj.removeEventListener('click', function(e){
    // perform your action
});
```

You can read about it in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Event_Handling).

Answer (score 0):

If that doesnt work, this is Javascript and you can apply Backbone Events to the objects - http://backbonejs.org/#Events